# Captcha Break or Text reader from Image: OCR-Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, ocr, captcha

I have a typical captcha image which contain only digits.

Ex. [image]

i want to extract **78614** from this image.

I tried few library & code using OCR-Python. But its returning 0.

**Sample Code-1**

```
from captcha_solver import CaptchaSolver

solver = CaptchaSolver('browser')
with open('captcha.png', 'rb') as inp:
raw_data = inp.read()
print(solver.solve_captcha(raw_data))
```

**Sample Code-2**

```
from PIL import Image

def p(img, letter):
    A = img.load()
    B = letter.load()
    mx = 1000000
    max_x = 0
    x = 0
    for x in range(img.size[0] - letter.size[0]):
        _sum = 0
        for i in range(letter.size[0]):
            for j in range(letter.size[1]):
                _sum = _sum + abs(A[x+i, j][0] - B[i, j][0])
        if _sum < mx :
            mx = _sum
            max_x = x
    return mx, max_x


def ocr(im, threshold=200, alphabet="0123456789abcdef"):
    img = Image.open(im)
    img = img.convert("RGB")
    box = (8, 8, 58, 18)
    img = img.crop(box)
    pixdata = img.load()

    letters = Image.open(im)
    ledata = letters.load()

    # Clean the background noise, if color != white, then set to black.
    for y in range(img.size[1]):
        for x in range(img.size[0]):
            if (pixdata[x, y][0] > threshold) \
                    and (pixdata[x, y][1] > threshold) \
                    and (pixdata[x, y][2] > threshold):

                pixdata[x, y] = (255, 255, 255, 255)
            else:
                pixdata[x, y] = (0, 0, 0, 255)

    counter = 0;
    old_x = -1;

    letterlist = []

    for x in range(letters.size[0]):
        black = True
        for y in range(letters.size[1]):
            if ledata[x, y][0] <> 0 :
                black = False
                break
        if black :
            if True :
                box = (old_x + 1, 0, x, 10)
                letter = letters.crop(box)
                t = p(img, letter);
                print counter, x, t
                letterlist.append((t[0], alphabet[counter], t[1]))
            old_x = x
            counter += 1

    box = (old_x + 1, 0, 140, 10)
    letter = letters.crop(box)
    t = p(img, letter)
    letterlist.append((t[0], alphabet[counter], t[1]))

    t = sorted(letterlist)
    t = t[0:5]  # 5-letter captcha

    final = sorted(t, key=lambda e: e[2])
    answer = ""
    for l in final:
        answer = answer + l[1]
    return answer

print(ocr('captcha.png'))
```

Has anyone had the opportunity to get/extract text from such typical captcha?

Answer (score 3):

You can use machine learning (neural networks) models to solve captchas and it will almost always outperform free OCR or any other method.

Here is a good starting point: https://medium.com/@ageitgey/how-to-break-a-captcha-system-in-15-minutes-with-machine-learning-dbebb035a710

Comment: I go through it. But it looks like it is not compatible with Pyhon 2.7+ versions. Is it right? Can you please provide me fair idea to implement in Python2.7? Thanks again.

Comment: Python2.7 will be no longer supported by 2020. Best use 3

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter
import numpy
import pytesseract
from PIL import ImageFilter
# thresold1 on the first stage
th1 = 140
th2 = 140 # threshold after blurring 
sig = 1.5 # the blurring sigma

from scipy import ndimage
original = Image.open("imagecaptcha.png")
original.save("original.png") # reading the image from the request
black_and_white =original.convert("L") #converting to black and white 
black_and_white.save("black_and_white.png")
first_threshold = black_and_white.point(lambda p: p > th1 and 255)
first_threshold.save("first_threshold.png")
blur=numpy.array(first_threshold) #create an image array
blurred = gaussian_filter(blur, sigma=sig)
blurred = Image.fromarray(blurred)
blurred.save("blurred.png")
final = blurred.point(lambda p: p > th2 and 255)
final = final.filter(ImageFilter.EDGE_ENHANCE_MORE)
final = final.filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
final.save("final.png")
number = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('final.png'))
print (number)
```

Comment: Please, avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.